# How can I use an annotation within a Validator class?

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I know it may sound weird but I need to fulfill such requirement in my project. Let's get down to the point.

I created a custom annotation which also uses `@Constraint` and implemented my custom validation logic in another class which implements `ConstraintValidator` interface. Unfortunately, `javax.validation` was never added as a dependency to this project(`@Valid`, `@NotBlank`, `@Email` etc. does not work) so I am forced to implement the `Validator` interface.

I know I can put my custom logic into `Validator`'s `validate()` method (tried it and it works) but I would prefer if I could keep my custom annotation in case another developer needs it in the future when the 'project standarts' change.

Can I somehow invoke my annotation's `isValid()` method from the Validator instance? Is this possible, or is it even still a sensible thing to do considering the fact I am not permitted to add a dependency?

TLDR code snippets: (writing on top of my head, sorry if there are any syntactic errors)

Custom annotation

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = myCustomValidator.class)
public @interface myCustomAnnotation {
    String message() default "dummy";
    Class[] groups() default {};
    Class[] payload() default {};

    class myCustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<myCustomAnnotation, Object> {
        // @Overload initialize
        // some code here

        // @Overload isValid
        public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
            // some code here, simple return for demonstration purposes
            return object != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Custom validator

```
public class customValidator implements Validator {
    //@Override supports
    //@Override validate
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        // somehow invoke my custom annotation here, no other validation code should be here
    }
}
```

Expected usage with validator

```
public ModelAndView customController(@ModelAttribute("form") CustomForm form, BindingResult errors) {
    Validator validator = new CustomValidator();
    validator.validate(form, errors);
    // expecting errors.hasErrors() to be filled
    // ...
}
```